# how to unlock inbound thruput to elasticsearch (7.8)

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, networking, load-testing

I am running load testing for elasticsearch. ( I am using rally framework ).
Tests are run on gcloud.
Single node elastic:
64 vCore CPU
3TB SSD drive
64 RAM

Client: 64 processes generated data
bulk update use case - bulk size is 50k jsons each bulk

test runs 24 - 48 hours

I did many different scenarios but inbound thruput is around 120 MB/s at a peak.
I tried multiple clients but overall thruput is not changing.
Client cpu is very low ( max 10%), elastic CPU is around 70%.

[image]

I tested the network and it is around 3GB/s - the network is not a bottleneck too.

Question:

1. What could block inbound traffic?
2. is there an elastic configuration to prevent the throttling and it's limit the traffic?